# How to ignore system host in nodejs & electron

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

In nodejs, I can rewrite `dns.lookup` and use `dns.resolve` to get the real IP for specified domain name. But how to do it in electron? i don't want to use `--host-rules` or other command line switch, because it's need preset address. so is there any way to use a similar method to nodejs in electron?